# Recursive list contains property

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class as follows:

```
public class Feature
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    public List<Feature> SubFeatures { get; set; } = new List<Feature>();
}
```

I then have a `List<Feature> features = new List<Feature>;` where I store all my features.

Now, I'd like to know if a particular `Feature` (by name) exists in my `features` variable.

However, it can exist at any level (`SubFeature` of the `SubFeature` of the `SubFeature` for example).

The closest I've gotten was this:

```
public bool FeatureExists(Feature feature, string name)
{
    return feature.Name == name || feature.SubFeatures.Select(subFeature => FeatureExists(subFeature, name)).Any(result => result);
}
```

But it involves having to use a for on the caller of `FeatureExists()` to pass one top level feature at a time to it.

I'm sure there's an easier way to do this, how can I do this properly?

Comment: Why do you need to use `for`? Can you not point to the top level parent of all features? This method is called recursively, so it will execute against every `SubFeatures` object .

Comment: what you could do is create a new variable named hierarchy.......from that your program could figure out how many time to recurse the lists subfeatures :)

Comment: I feel like I'm misreading something... are you basically asking for `features.Any(x => FeatureExists(x, featureName))`?

Comment: You presumably need to loop through your top level list of features somehow. If you don't want a `for` you could just use linq and `Any`. ie `features.Any(x=>FeatureExists(x, name))`.

Comment: @grek40 yes, you're absolutely correct, I'm officially a tool. I blame it on the lack of sleep...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a recursive method like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Feature> FeatureAndSubFeatures(Feature feature)
{
    yield return feature;

    foreach (var subFeature in feature.SubFeatures)
    {
        foreach (var child in FeatureAndSubFeatures(subFeature))
        {
            yield return child;
        }
    }
}
```

Then use it:

```
FeatureAndSubFeatures(feature).Any(x => x.Name == name);
```

Another option is to put this method on Feature itself, called something like SelfAndSubFeaturesRecursive().

This approach - writing a method to recursively flatten the tree, rather than writing a specific method to search for a Feature with the given name - is flexible, as you can use it to search the tree for any node based on any criterion, or any subset of nodes, rather than being specialised for just finding nodes with a particular name.

You can also write it to take a collection of features to start with. Something like:

```
public IEnumerable<Feature> FeaturesAndSubFeatures(IEnumerable<Feature> features)
{
    foreach (var feature in features)
    {
        yield return feature;

        foreach (var child in FeaturesAndSubFeatures(feature.SubFeatures))
        {
            yield return child;
        }
    }
}
```

This is only useful if you're always starting with a collection of features, but saves a `SelectMany` in the event that you do.

Comment: Ok, that's pretty similar to what I've got, but the problem I still have is that I start with a `List<Feature>` and the method accepts a single Feature. How can I search through all of those?

Comment: You could write `features.SelectMany(x => FeatureAndSubFeatures(x)).Any(...)`, or you could rewrite `FeatureAndSubFeatures` to take an `IEnumerable<Feature>`.

Comment: While there are quite a few correct answers here (and as pointed out in comments the easiest thing would be for me to just do `features.Any(x => FeatureExists(x, "whatever"))`, this approach is far more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

I try to avoid recursion whenever possible. This is a version without:

```
public bool FeatureExists(Feature feature, string name)
{
    var featureQueue = new Queue<Feature>();
    featureQueue.Enqueue(feature);
    while (featureQueue.Count > 0)
    {
        Feature current = featureQueue.Dequeue();
        if (feature.Name == name)
            return true;
        foreach (Feature f in current.SubFeatures)
            featureQueue.Enqueue(f);
    }
    return false;
}
```

---

If you find this less readable as commented you can use a generic extension method and use it whenever you need recursive checks, for example:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool RecursiveCheck<T>(this T rootItem, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> getChildrenFunc, Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        var queue = new Queue<T>();
        queue.Enqueue(rootItem);
        while (queue.Count > 0)
        {
            T current = queue.Dequeue();
            if (predicate(current))
                return true;
            foreach (T child in getChildrenFunc(current))
                queue.Enqueue(child);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Test-Feature:

```
Feature f1 = new Feature
{
    Name = "1", SubFeatures = new List<Feature> { new Feature {Name="1.1", SubFeatures = new List<Feature> {new Feature {Name= "thename" } } }}
};
```

This simple one-liner remains:

```
bool containsName = f1.RecursiveCheck<Feature>(f => f.SubFeatures, f => f.Name == "thename");
```

Comment: Can you elaborate as to why you try to avoid recursion? I'd be curious to hear more about that.

Comment: @cogumel0: recursion is often more difficult to understand, it's easier to pruduce bugs, it can cause `StackOverFlowExceptions` etc.

Comment: But I personally find your code harder to follow as oppose to the current recursive approach. The `StackOverflow` part I agree though.

Comment: Recursion on an inherently recursive structure (like a tree) is not really harder or more error prone than other iteration techniques if you ask me.

Comment: Read [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1004806/Recursion-Good-Bad-or-Indifferent). I don't understand why a stack is more appropriate or efficient here canton. I'm returning `true` immediately once the feature is found

Comment: I was half asleep when I wrote my comment, and deleted it seconds afterwards after re-reading it.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I agree with Emad that this code is harder to follow than for example what canton7 proposed.

Comment: @cogumel0: point taken, so i've added an extension method which you can use instead

Answer (score 0):

You want to make a separate recursive method that does this for you.'
Try this:

```
public bool FeatureExists(Feature feature, string name) {
    if(feature.Name == name) {
        return true;
    }   
    if(!feature.SubFeatures.isEmpty) {
        foreach(Feature subFeature in feature.SubFeatures){
            FeatureExists(subFeature, name)
        }
    }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm not sure if this is what you are asking but if you want cleaner code you may write your function as an extension method and use LINQ instead of for loops to get cleaner code.

```
public static bool FeatureExists(this Feature feature, string name)
{
    return feature.Name == name || feature.SubFeatures.Select(subFeature => FeatureExists(subFeature, name)).Any(result => result);
}
```

And then

```
List<Feature> mainFeatures = new List<Feature>();
mainFeatures.Any(obj => obj.FeatureExists("abc"));
```

If you want event shorter and cleaner code you might consider having a feature as a parent of all features like a mother feature and then call your recursive method over that.

But anyway consider making your method an extension method.

Comment: Your code can be simplified to `mainFeatures.Any(obj => obj.FeatureExists("abc"))`. However, it answers the question quite nicely.

Comment: @cogumel0 Thanks I tried to answer quickly missed this.

Answer (score 0):

the following should recurse through all the lists and populate "result" with       all the possible features contained in the entire hierarchy

```
 public class Feature
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string DisplayName { get; set; }

        public List<Feature> SubFeatures { get; set; } = new List<Feature>();
    }
```

**other class**

```
List<feature> result = new List<feature>();

public void FindItems(Feature yourFeature)
{
   result.add(yourFeature);
   foreach(Feature feature in yourFeature)
   {
      if(feature.SubFeatures.count != 0)
      {
         foreach(Feature subfeature in feature)
         {
            FindItems(subfeature);
         }
      }
      else
      {
         result.add(feature);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: It's much more efficient to generate an `IEnumerable<Feature>` using `yield return`, particularly if the search is going to stop after you've found the first node with a given name. Your approach will flatten the entire tree, even if the node being search for is the first one.

Comment: flattening the entire tree is what he wanted, im just wondering, what would happen with your recursion if the hierarchy was 5-10 deep ?(legitimate question, cause by what i can follow it would only go about 3 deep)

Comment: Sure, but he doesn't need to have the whole tree contained in a list. He just needs to search the tree and **stop** when he finds an item which matches his criterion. Putting the entire tree in a new list is a waste of time and space.